# Email Signature style are messing up when I send email from Outlook to Gmail

Tags: html-email, email-client, email-templates

I want signature to show differently in desktop layout and in mobile layout. Its a two column layout on desktop and I want to show them one above the other in mobile. I am achieving this but there are two issues.

- Signature is rendering as desktop layout in outlook app, samsung email app and can be other (as I don't have the tool to test it on all client apps) but rendering as mobile layout on Gmail app.
- When I send mail from Outlook and see it in Gmail mobile app then the styles are messed up. The layout just have to appear on top to one another but I can't figure it out where are the extra spaces coming from. (images are attached)

[image: Desktop Layout Image]

[image: Mobile layout on Gmail app]

And here is my code. I am not expert just a beginner so any help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE">
</head>

<body>

    <table class="as-template" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top">
                    <table class="as-logo-wrapper" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="260" align="left" style="vertical-align: top;padding-right: 10px">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div style="padding: 0; margin: 0" id="as-logo">
                                        <img style="display: inline-block; width: 250px;" alt="Ascent Security Logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x66" width="250" height="66">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table class="personal-details" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="290" align="left" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;margin-top: 8px;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="person-main" style="background-color: #2A3385;border-spacing: 0;color: #fff;vertical-align: middle" valign="middle">
                                <td style="margin: 0; padding: 2px 0 2px 5px" valign="middle">
                                    Mehmood Ahmad, Managing Director
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="person-phone" style="padding: 0;border-spacing: 0; margin: 0">
                                <td style="padding: 5px 0 0 5px; margin: 0;">
                                    Phone: 1234 123 123
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="person-contact" style="padding: 0;border-spacing: 0; margin: 0">
                                <td style="padding: 0 0 0 5px; margin: 0;">
                                    Email: mehmood@example.com.au
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="person-po-box" style="padding: 0;border-spacing: 0; margin: 0">
                                <td style="padding: 10px 0 0 5px ; margin: 0;">
                                    PO Box 123, Street Number City
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="person-address" style="padding: 0;border-spacing: 0; margin: 0">
                                <td style="padding: 0 0 0 5px; margin: 0;">
                                    ACN 123 123 132
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are using two tables, `as-logo-wrapper` left  and `personal-details` on the right. Place both in two column table and break the columns into rows using media queries in mobile versions. _sending tests from outlook are not the best testing ground. use something like mailchimp._

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

How can I break them into columns in mobile versions because as far as I know media queries are not supported in emails.

I don't have mailchimp account so I can't use that. I have to send email through outlook desktop app, gmail, outlook web app, gmail mobile app etc.... therefore I am checking in all of these.

Comment: Media queries are supported by 99% of email clients according to Litmus. You will need to use `th` rather than `td` in order to break into columns though. Look at litmus blog articles to get an idea as to how this can be done

Comment: I need to send email through outlook so are media queries supported by outlook too because I tried that in the past and failed. If they are supported then how can I use them. It will be nice if you link me to brief resource because I am unable to find that.

Comment: Outlook doesnt read media queries. Search for litmus blog, it has a lot of resources.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help